# The use of functions rename(), is_readable(), fopen(), fgetcsv() is discouraged Magento 2

Tags: magento2, file-upload

I am checking uploaded file is readable by `is_readable` function of php but in coding standard check it's shows

> The use of function is_readable() is discouraged

same error show ablow all function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per Magento 2 coding standard you should use magento function instead of direct php functions

**You can use `isReadable()` function of class `Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Driver\File`**

Also available other function like use `fileGetCsv()` for `fgetcsv()`
use `fileOpen()` for fopen()

You can find more file specific functions from

> vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Driver/File.php

```
protected $_fileSystem;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Driver\File $fileSystem,
    ...
) {
    $this->_fileSystem = $fileSystem;
}
```

Comment: Working awesome @prince thanks a lot